# Add bottom border only at chapter name, not in chapter number

Tags: formatting, titlesec

I am trying to achieve something like the photo below using the `titlesec` package but I couldn't manage to add a border only at chapter name. Any ideas? :
[image]

My code snippet

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\Huge\bfseries}
{{\fontsize{50pt}{1em}\textnormal{\thechapter}}}{1ex}{}
[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}{\titlerule[0.6mm]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{linegoal}
\newcommand{\ultitle}[1]{\makebox[\linegoal][r]{#1}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{ \bfseries\huge}{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont
\bfseries\raisebox{-6pt}{\scalebox{3}{\thechapter}}}{4ex} 
{\mbox{}\rlap{\rule[-6pt]{\linegoal}{1.6pt}}\ultitle}
    
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it would be better if the line was aligned with the chapter number like the photo but this approach is very good too!

Comment: @George21: I've updated my answer to satisfy this condition. I I also have adjusted the rule thickness to the thickness of the chapter number stem (the values were found by trial and error, so it should be adjusted to your real font).

Comment: Your solution works fine but when I migrated it in my document I had some issues with the linegoal package in numberless sections. That's why I added this style for the numberless chapters.
```\titleformat
{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
{\Huge\bfseries\raggedleft}
{}
{0pt}
{}
[\normalsize\vspace*{1em}{\titlerule[1.6pt]}]```

Seems that it's working, I don't know exactly what was the problem.

Comment: Oh! Yes. I didn't think you might have numberless chapters. Of course, the whole code is designed for numbered chapters. Your  solution is fine.